# If someone ping a member who is AFK it send a message | Discord.js / mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

i have been trying to make a afk and endafk command for my bot using mongodb.My command work fine but i would like so when you ping someone who is afk it send a message like this: This user is currently AFK!\n**${afkReason}**,but this isnt working.I have been trying to fix it but it still doesn't work so if someone could help me that would be nice thanks you.
Here is my afk command:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const db = process.env.DB


mongoose.connect(db)

const Afk = require(process.env.ROOTDIR + '/models/afk.js')


const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.help = {
    name: "afk",
    aliases: ['afk', 'setafk', 'afkset'],
    category: 'misc',
    description: "Set your activity to afk",
    usage: " ",
    cooldown: 0,
    args: false
};     

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    await message.delete()

    let afkReason = args.slice(0).join(" ")
    if(!afkReason) return(afkReason = "No reason provided")

    const nAfk = new Afk({
        username: message.author.tag,
        userID: message.author.id,
        afkReason: afkReason,
        guildID: message.guild.id,
        time: message.createdAt.toUTCString()
    })

nAfk.save()
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

message.reply(`is now afk: **${afkReason}.**`)
message.member.setNickname("[AFK] " + message.author.username);

// this is the part where it isnt working
if (message.mentions.member) {
    message.reply(`This user is currently AFK!\n**${afkReason}**`);
    }
}
```

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

:)
You actually check message in your afk command 
You need to put this code :

```js
if (message.mentions.member) {
    message.reply(`This user is currently AFK!\n**${afkReason}**`);
}
```

inside message event, and check if member mentionned is afk

I hope my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple Problem
When you do

```js
if(!afkReason) return(afkReason = "No reason provided")
```

The return actually ends the function (the `run` function)there and no code after that will be executed.
So try doing it without the `return`

```js
if(!afkReason){ afkReason = "No reason provided" }
```

**Now where you said the actual error was**.

As you can see `message.mentions.member` dosen't exist. It should be `message.mentions.members.first()`
Then run a `find`
**Example:**

```js
if(message.mentions.members.first(){
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    Afk.find({
        userID: member.user.id
    }).then( afkstat => {
        message.channel.send(`The user is afk.\nReason: ${afkstat.afkReason}`);
    }).catch(console.log)
}
```

You might wanna put this in the `chient.on("message", message=> {});` function

Comment: hi uhm sorry for late answer.First thanks for taking your time to help me.The thing is now whenever i ping someone it say that the user is afk blablabla even if the user isnt afk and even if i am not afk.Do you have an idea on how to fix that please? Thanks again!